# VirtualBox no Internet connection

Tags: networking, virtualbox

**Configuration:**

OS: Windows 10 Home, latest patches
VB: 5.1.22 r115126

**Problem:**

All of a sudden, my Virtual Box (Ubuntu 17.04, Elementary) can't have any Internet access inside the box. Looking at the Network tab of that VB, only one network adapter is found:

[image]

**Tried Solutions:**

- Create a new VB, same issue: no Internet access inside the box;
- Reinstall the Oracle VB (by uninstall first and reboot), same issue.

Need your help here.

Don't know if it is off-topic by putting on "virtualbox" tag, if so, moderators please help to tag it correctly.

**Update**

I now manually created a Bridged Adapter:[image]

The issue now is that I can ping to Internet but can't browse in my Firefox and `apt update` also fails due to no network connection.

Both network adapters have their own IP:

- 192.168.0.78, which is the IP assigned by my router;
- 10.0.2.15, which is the IP assigned by the VB

**Update on May 03**

Managed to create another adapter and the two adapters are now:

- Bridged
- Virtual Host-only

The Ubuntu VB is now running and OK to connect to Internet.

The new problem is now when I use Vagrant to create another VB instance, it only has one adapter (NAT), which proves to be not able to access the Internet. I tried to manually change the network configuration for that VM in VB but everytime I run `vagrant up` the configuration is reverted to NAT. I looked into my `Vagrantfile` and did not find any place to make my changes permanent.

Any hints?

Comment: probably the issue is with the OS inside the box. does the client OS get a valid IP address? what if you create a new box with Windows in it?